# Unable to read memory while using std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, std, shared-ptr

I have a class that has a `std::shared_ptr` as a member, which is later initialised in a function. However, I don't believe it's working correctly as when I debug it and inspect the layout of the shared_ptr object, it shows `<Unable to read memory>`when I try to view the inner pointer (the class the `shared_ptr` is pointing to).

The first three file snippets below are from a DLL project that a second project references. The IGLSLProgram.h file is included in this second project so that the exported class defined in the DLL can be used.

---

IGLSLProgram.h (Interface in the DLL)

```
class IGLSLProgram;
typedef IGLSLProgram *GLSLProgramHandle;
typedef shared_ptr<IGLSLProgram> IGLSLProgramPtr;
extern "C" COMMON_API GLSLProgramHandle APIENTRY getGLSLProgram();

class IGLSLProgram {
public:
    IGLSLProgram() {}
    ~IGLSLProgram() {}

    // ...

    virtual void release() = 0;
};
```

---

GLSLProgram.h (Implements IGLSLProgram)

```
#include "IGLSLProgram.h"

class GLSLProgram : public IGLSLProgram {
public:
    GLSLProgram() {}
    ~GLSLProgram() {}

    // ...

    void release();
};
```

---

GLSLProgram.cpp (Defines GLSLProgram implementation)

```
#include "GLSLProgram.h"

COMMON_API GLSLProgramHandle APIENTRY getGLSLProgram() {
    return new GLSLProgram;
}

// ...
```

---

Program.h (Program that uses the DLL)

```
#include "Common\IProgram.h"
#include "Common\IGLSLProgram.h"

class Program : public IProgram {
protected:
    IGLSLProgramPtr shaderProgram;
public:
    Program() {}
    ~program() {}

    void createShaderProgram();

    // ...
};
```

---

Program.cpp (Defines class declared in Program.h)

```
#include "Program.h"
#include "Common\IGLSLProgram.h"

// ...

void Program::createShaderProgram() {
    shaderProgram = IGLSLProgramPtr(getGLSLProgram(), mem_fn(&IGLSLProgram::release));

    // ...
```

}

---

When inspecting the last line in the Program.cpp snippet, I see that shaderProgram has the following layout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZrkF.jpg

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by making `IGLSLProgram shaderProgram;` in *Program.h* static. This is fine for my purpose as the Program class should only ever have one instance anyway.

---

Program.h (Resolved)

```
#include "Common\IProgram.h"
#include "Common\IGLSLProgram.h"

class Program : public IProgram {
protected:
    static IGLSLProgramPtr shaderProgram;
public:
    Program() {}
    ~program() {}

    void createShaderProgram();

    // ...
};
```

---

What I am not sure of is why this helps and why a `std::shared_ptr` cannot be a non-static member in a class. If anyone could explain this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a `shared_ptr` being a non-static data member. I suspect the debugger got some problems, maybe because your project is a DLL. Try to access the pointer from within the program and output the result (e.g. via `OutputDebugString`). (Did you compile with optimizations?)

Comment: The strange thing is the shared_ptr works perfectly in the file and local scope, but not when declared as a class member. I will try your suggestions and also downgrade the project to VS2012 to see if it's a VS2013 Preview debugger issue.

Comment: Just disabled optimisations (/Od) for the project. Seems to have done the trick! Thanks very much :)